# 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, vb.net, innerhtml

I have the following:

```
<div id="valueboxes" style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;width:100%;height:200px">
```

However, every time I use the following:

```
document.getElementById("valueboxes").innerHTML = html;
```

I get this error:

```
'innerHTML': object is null or undefined
```

Am I doing something wrong?

The html is a table var being appended too by javascript in a for loop using `+=`.

Comment: Where is this code executing? It's likely that the DOM isn't ready for manipulation.

Comment: There is no HTML in the code you included in this question. Please show the HTML inside the "valueboxes" div so we can help you.

Comment: @AmandaSmith: If you have a lot of other DOM manipulation going on, [you might want to check out jQuery](http://jquery.com/). That way, you can simply use `$(function(){ /* Your DOM code here * /});` It will simplify a bunch of other things too.

Comment: DomReady event occurs before window.onload, you'd better use jQuery

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you are executing your code before DOM is fully loaded.

This *should* work:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('valueboxes').innerHTML = html;
};
```

Or you can simply put your javascript code just before `</body>` tag with no need to use `onload` there.

Comment: You should use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) over `onload`.

Comment: Mine is blank even though the chrome inspector shows it's not. I'm trying it on a div and on an h1